# How to insert a LaTeX environment around a block of text in emacs?

Tags: emacs, latex

I'm using emacs with cdlatex-mode to edit LaTeX files.  I would like to know how to insert a LaTeX environment around a block of text that is already written so that the `\begin{}` goes before the selected text and the `\end{}` goes after the selected text.  I've tried to use cdlatex-environment function but doing so erases the selected text.

Comment: Try the specialist latex stackexchange.

Comment: @Marcin Since this is an Emacs question it might still make sense here.

Comment: @N.N. Sure, but OP might get more joy there.

Comment: @Marcin It is more (formally) on topic there but my experience is that it is easier to get help with Emacs on SO and SU than on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### AUCTeX

If you use [auctex](/questions/tagged/auctex):

1. Mark the block of text you want to enclose in an environment.
2. Press <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>.
3. Enter an environment type of your choice (you can only type some characters and use tab completion) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Environments.html#Environments) for details.

Note that there is a similar method to enclose marked text in macros. Do as 1–3 but instead press <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd> or <kbd>C-c Enter</kbd> instead. See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Completion.html#Completion) for details.

### YASnippet

If you use [YASnippet](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/) you can create a snippet with similar behavior as above. For example you can use the following (you have replace "keybinding" with a proper keybinding):

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: LaTeX environment
# key: "keybinding"
# --
\begin{$1}
  `yas/selected-text`$0
\end{$1}
```

If you want a snippet for macros too you can use something like the following:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: LaTeX macro
# key: "keybinding"
# --
\$1{`yas/selected-text`$0}
```

### Elisp

Even if I recommend the above approaches there might be situations where you want instead to use some simple elisp function. The following is just something rough which has far less functionality than the above approaches:

```lisp
(defun ltx-environment (start end env)
  "Insert LaTeX environment."
  (interactive "r\nsEnvironment type: ")
  (save-excursion
    (if (region-active-p)
    (progn
      (goto-char end)
      (newline)
      (insert "\\end{" env "}")
      (goto-char start)
      (insert "\\begin{" env "}") (newline))
      (insert "\\begin{" env "}") (newline) (newline)
      (insert "\\end{" env "} "))))
```

And for macros if you want that too:

```lisp
(defun ltx-macro (start end env)
  "Insert LaTeX macro."
  (interactive "r\nsMacro: ")
  (save-excursion
    (if (region-active-p)
    (progn
      (goto-char end) (insert "}")
      (goto-char start) (insert "\\" env "{"))
      (insert "\\" env "{}"))))
```

To use them put them in your .emacs and do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ltx-environment` or `ltx-macro` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not using auctex.  I'm using cdlatex-mode, org-cdlatex-mode and org-mode.

Comment: @DavidGagnon Would you be interested in a yasnippet solution? I think that you easily can make yasnippets similar to the above commands. There might however be conflicts between Org-mode and yasnippet, http://orgmode.org/manual/Conflicts.html#Conflicts.

Comment: Thank you! I have installed yasnippets and created a simple snippet that does exactly what I was looking for.  To enclose the marked text within the environment, I used `# expand-env: ((yas/wrap-around-region 't))` in the snippet's header.

Comment: @DavidGagnon That is good to hear. I have added a snippet to my answer for completeness but I used `yas/selected-text` instead. I guess it leads to similar behavior though.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14507231/1243435) by Tikhon Jelvis, I had a look at the latex mode documentation (C-h m) and found mention of the function

```
latex-insert-block
```

which seems to do exactly what you want.

The shortcut key is C-c C-t (whenever you are in latex mode).