# How do I run LateX on a emacs file in Linux?

Tags: linux, emacs, latex

I'm an absolute beginner and I've never worked on a Linux machine before. I was working on a emacs file from home on a virtual machine. Now that I'm on a Linux machine at school, how do I run LateX on the file and view the dvi? I was able to open emacs and load the file.

Comment: What major mode do you use in emacs to edit the file? You can run latex from the shell, just enter `latex file` and that's it.

Comment: You mean you were working on a .tex file in emacs, right?

Comment: You can run any shell command from inside emacs, see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Shell.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use `C-c C-c`, which is bound to the function `tex-compile`.

Here's a useful hint: you can use `C-h m` to bring up the documentation for a mode. This documentation usually has a list of the keybindings associated with the mode. In this case, there's a list under the heading "Special Commands:" which includes `C-c C-c` `tex-compile` as well as some other commands which may be useful in the future.

One of the best things about Emacs is that it's self-documenting, so learning to use the help system (keys starting with `C-h`) is invaluable.