# How to create an inline latex block in emacs (like \emph{...})

Tags: emacs, latex

This SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881012/1243435) asks for an emacs shortcut for creating a latex block, and one solution (proposed by me, but just coming from the emacs documentation) is to use `C-c C-t`.

Is there something similar that would create an 'inline' block without creating any new lines, like for turning

```
blah blah Hello World blah blah
```

into

```
blah blah \emph{Hello World} blah blah
```

for example?

Comment: Some looking into `TeX-font-list` may help, perhaps

Comment: @Sean, I couldn't find that in emacs documentation, could you help me out please (I looked in function and variable documentation with C-h f and C-h v).

Comment: C-h v `TeX-font-list` works for me... Make sure AUCTeX (I hope you're using AUCTeX, undeniably the most comprehensive Emacs mode for TeX/Friends) is up-to-date, and remember C-h v is case sensitive.

Comment: Ahh, I am not using AUCTeX. Probably I should, but to be honest I am doing pretty well at the moment without.

Comment: Fair enough.  So to clarify, can we assume that you're using the default Emacs support for TeX (ie `TeX-mode`)?

Comment: Well an emacs 'C-h m' tells me I am in `LaTeX mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do.  With cursor before the "Hello World" I type: `\emph C-M-SPC C-M-SPC {`

The closing brace is inserted together with the opening brace, because I use `electric-pair-mode`.

You might be able to use completion to speed up typing the `\emph`, tho it's sufficiently short that it's probably not work the trouble.

Comment: This might require some additional fiddeling with the terminal setup if you run `-nw`. For instance, my terminal does not produce an escape sequence for `C-M-SPC`, it becomes just `M-SPC` which in turn in interpreted as `ALT+SPACE` by my window manager and results in displaying the main menu of the terminal window. But of course there are alternative ways of marking a region that do work in terminal mode.

Comment: Okay I see -- the `C-M-SPC` (which I am actually doing as `C-M-@` at the moment because my Autohotkey remappings are not set up properly) moves the mark to the end of Hello and then to the end of World. However it only works with the `electric-par-mode` enabled, as you say. Trouble is that `electric-pair-mode` requires a bit of a mind-shift for me at the moment. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Thomas -- I would like to know more about what 'additional fiddling' I could do to fix the issue with C-M-SPC becoming C-SPC. I currently have an open question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/15899963/1243435) on Autohotkey + Emacs in Cygwin and you may have some good ideas.

Comment: My good idea is to upgrade to a Free operating system, such as a dsitribution of GNU/Linux.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I don't use Windows, but am already following Stefan's good idea. You might want to consider asking a question on superuser.com.

Comment: People, do not worry! I have got Linux at home. This is the workplace, not much I can do. Even having Cygwin at work is unusual in my experience.